# How to make the "shake" commands easier?

Tags: ios, pages, notes.app, undo-redo

When I want to undo some typing on Notes or Pages, I have to shake my ipod-touch like a crazy (and afraid that it may throw from my hand).

Isn't there a way to configure the "shake sensitivity", or change this command for, say, a button?

Comment: I can't think of an answer to this question more useful than "No", unfortunately. Unless there's something available via jailbreaking...

Comment: Try pivoting/tilting along the home-/power-button axis while shaking the whole device up and down - i.e. rotating your hand while moving it up/down. This may help to trigger the "shake" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 5, there is no way in stock iOS to adjust the shake gesture sensitivity.

Comment: Ok, the @iolsmit commend also helped me.

Answer (score 3):

In settings use accessibility to turn on assistive touch. That gives you a virtual home button which includes many things including shake. Touch the virtual home button, touch device.  One of the options under device is shake.

Comment: That's an alternative, but much more complicated.